# Python Requests '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1091)'

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, https, python-requests

I've tried to execute a GET with **python requests** on a Website (that perfectly works when visited with Firefox or Google Chrome) but it fails with the following exception:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.example.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1091)')))
```

the interesting thing is that if I execute the GET on an other Subdomain (of the same website) it is:

- api.example.com **Exception**
- app.example.com **It Works**

and **BOTH are certified with the SAME ROOT CA** and both works on Firefox or Google Chrome.

In particular the code is the following (a very simple request)

```
import requests
import json

s = requests.Session()

# execute the get
r = s.get("https://api.example.com/"
```

and Throws the Exception:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.example.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1091)')))
```

Insted if I execute:

```
r = s.get("https://app.example.com/"
```

it works without any problem!

And I remark that boot are Signed and Cerfiticated by the same Root CA.
And Both works correctly if visited with Firefox or Google Chrome.

I don't know what to do...
Thanks for any hint...

**p.s.**
All the CAs are updated to the latest version.

And the versions of the packages are:

- urllib3-1.26.6
- certifi-2021.5.30

Comment: True... Sorry, I've updated it!

Comment: _example.com_ is just a placeholder ?

Comment: Exactly, to not post the real website

Comment: Check the site against [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) and look especially for "chain issues" - which point to a server side misconfiguration. Browser can usually work around this misconfiguration so it seems to work. Most non-browser tools though cannot work around this and fail.

Comment: @steffen-ullrich I've tried it and it says: "Chain issues: Incomplete", is there a way to work arount it in python requests?

Comment: @Samuele: Then this is a duplicate question. The answers to the linked questions also shows ways to work around this problem in Python requests.